# Error at casting variable PHP

Tags: php, casting, drupal-7

Hello I try to load a node at a view using the node_load() function which takes an integer argument. I take the node id by `$nid=$fields['nid']->content;` and I try to load the node by calling `node_load($nid)` but it fails. After experimenting i figured out that $nid is String instead of integer so I try to cast to an int but it returns me 0. Can you help me?

```
$nid=$fields['nid']->content;

print gettype($nid);

print $nid;
print intval($nid);
print (int) $nid;
```

Output:

string 3 0 0

---

After executing `var_dump($nid);` this is the output

```
 " string(36) "
```

---

Another try:

```
$nid=$fields['nid']->content;

print $nid;

echo (int) trim($nid)
```

output:
3 0

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($nid);` (Take the output from the source code)?

Comment: What do you mean output from the source code? The only way to execute php is on server

Comment: If you look at the html output do: Right click -> view source code and take the output from there

Comment: I updated the question with the var_dump

Comment: String with 36 in length?

Comment: 1. I think you should also have something after: `string(36)` e.g. `string(36) "xy"`, so add this also 2. Do you think `string(36)` and `3` matches?

Comment: actually there are a lot of whitespaces. I don't know why they aren't show in the print.

Comment: @JmRag ^ Try to use: `echo (int) trim($nid);`

Comment: @Rizier123 it doesn't works either.. I update the question again.

Comment: `$fields['nid']` is an object?